# Dirac equation plane with solution

Tags: dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

Using the Dirac equation with or $p=$ zero and the $\gamma^0$ matrix defined as
$$\gamma^0=\begin{pmatrix}0 & \sigma_0 \\ \sigma_0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}0 & \bf{I} \\ \bf{I} & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

I get eigenvalues $\pm m=\pm E$ with $\hbar=c=1$.

Finding the eigenvectors I get the four possible 
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

I see in other texts they are using 
$$\gamma^0=\begin{pmatrix}\bf{I} & \\ & -\bf{I}\end{pmatrix}$$
and get possible eigenvectors 
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Should I expect a different result from my definition of $\gamma^0$ for the eigenvectors?

Comment: Hi! Your first set of eigenvalues is wrong: **0** is the null vector, and it is the *trivial* eigenvector of anything; **1** is the sum of the first two vectors. The right eigenvectors are something like: (1,0,1,0), (1,0,-1,0), (0,1,0,1) and (0,1,0,-1).

Comment: thanks :) They are the nontrivial answers I got too but with two positive eigenvalues m=E and and two negative m=-E

Answer (score 0):

Gamma matrices are define as:
$$
\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu \} =2\eta_{\mu\nu}
$$

Matrices $S \gamma_\mu S^{-1}$ are also satisfying this equation. So we have different bases for gamma matrices. Now easy understand how your answers are related.